# Great grandchildren ThenInclude() is failing

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following query. In the code it's Signup.Effort.Parent

```
   var user = await context.AppUsers
        .Include(user => user.Following!)
        .ThenInclude(org => org.News)
        .Include(user => user.Interests)
        .Include(user => user.Signups!)
        .ThenInclude(signup => signup.Effort)
        .ThenInclude(effort => effort.Parent)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Id == _combinedUser.AppUser.Id);
```

If I remove `ThenInclude(effort => effort.Parent)` then everything runs fine. If I leave it in then throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Warning: Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation, either via 'Include' or through projection, but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default, Entity Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery', which can potentially result in slow query performance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'.
The thread 0x14d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\7.0.10\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.10\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\bin\Debug\net7.0\DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.10\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in LouisHowe.web.dll
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.10\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.ErrorBoundary: Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: The expression 'effort.Parent' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'effort.Parent' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeTree(IncludeTreeNode includeTreeNode, Expression expression, Boolean setLoaded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude, Boolean setLoaded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LouisHowe.web.Pages.User.Dashboard.ReadEventsFromDb() in C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\User\Dashboard.razor.cs:line 118
   at LouisHowe.web.Pages.User.Dashboard.ReadEventsFromDb() in C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\User\Dashboard.razor.cs:line 169
   at LouisHowe.web.Pages.User.Dashboard.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\User\Dashboard.razor.cs:line 104
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
LouisHowe.web.Pages.User.Dashboard: Error: Error: 50666d4d-59aa-4a75-bc84-7d6c11445c12
```

The relevant part of each class:

```
public class Signup : IAuditTrail, IPrimaryEntities, IDisableable
{
    public Effort Effort { get; set; }
    public int EffortId { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class Effort : IAuditTrail, IPrimaryEntities, IDisableable
{
    public Organization Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; private set; }
    public List<Signup>? Signups { get; set; }
}

public class Event : Effort
{
}

public class Organization : IPrimaryEntities, IAuditTrail, IDisableable
{
    public List<Event>? Events { get; private set; }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't like this?

Comment: The exception basically tells you what to do, you can add `.AsSplitQuery()` before the `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` call.

Comment: @DavidG First off thank you. I've been using EF for 6 months and this is the first I've heard of this. And clearly should have known it by now. If you make your comment an answer, happy to accept it. **Also**, should I be using Split Queries globally? Reading this it strikes me that that will be better in almost all cases for pulling in associated collections.

Comment: Actually, there's a sub-error below that, is that the bit causing your actual problem? `The expression 'effort.Parent' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access:`

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I just found that too after adding `AsSplitQuery()`. The thing is, it's a property. Could this be happening because it's reading them in from the DB as Event objects and the property is in the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error likely has to do with that you are going from Effort to Organization, but Organization has a list of Event which extend Effort, and EF most likely isn't liking that too much. If you want organizations to split references of "Efforts" between "Events" vs. other types, I would suggest using a List of "Efforts" that is mapped for EF to use, then use unmapped sub-lists that can split the efforts into collections of Events etc. Those sub-lists cannot be used in Linq Queries, for that you would have to go to the base Efforts.

```
public class Organization : IPrimaryEntities, IAuditTrail, IDisableable
{
    public List<Effort> Efforts { get; private set; } = new();

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Event> Events => Efforts.OfType<Event>();
}
```

Overall with entities I don't generally recommend using inheritance if at all avoidable when it comes to entities participating under an aggregate root. Sometimes the justification for inheritance is merely that multiple different classes/tables seem to share the same fields, where it should only be considered where these classes are interchangeable with one another where referenced. I.e. it is merely a fact that an organization is linked to an Event or any other sub-class, rather than there are expectations that only certain subclasses participate in that relationship.

Alternatively if an Organization only applies to Events:

```
public abstract class Effort : IAuditTrail, IPrimaryEntities, IDisableable
{
    public List<Signup>? Signups { get; set; }
}

public class Event : Effort
{
    public int ParentId { get; private set; }
    public Organization Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : IPrimaryEntities, IAuditTrail, IDisableable
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; private set; } = new();
}
```

This form of inheritance is best served by Table-per-Type or Table-per-Concrete inheritance support in EF/DB rather than Table-per-Hierarchy. This is more of a case where the inheritance is more of an expression of what common fields the entities have, rather than their roles in the data relationships as a base class/interface might express the common Id column, IsActive column, etc. that all entities share.

The other warning about `AsSplitQuery` is a new feature for EF Core which warns about scenarios resulting in a lot of Joins which can produce a significant Cartesian Product in terms of the total # of rows and columns the resulting query would return. In these cases, the new `AsSplitQuery` can break up the expression to run separate queries across the related tables resulting in a smaller total dataset coming back. Joins result in an a x b x c x d scenario based on the # of columns and rows returned by the combinations of a, b, c, and d tables. `AsSplitQuery` can reduce this to more of an a + b + c + d in terms of the amount of data coming back.

Comment: First off thanks. Advice please. This app manages volunteers. An effort (Job or Event) is a specific bit of work someone signs up for. A job is do it whenever (web design) while an event is a specific time/place (staffing a booth). So really Event is everything in Job plus the time specific parts. In this case, how best to design the DB schema and how best to specify the classes? Because I can have distinct EF objects but a shared IJob or IEffort interface. Your suggestion? Or... I have just the Event table and the non Job parts are all nullable? TIA

Comment: Hi again. Am I correct in understanding your comment about `AsSplitQuery` to say that 99% of the time it's a good idea? And not doing it is for the rare cases where you really do want a tightly joined object returned?

Comment: Split queries have some limitations particularly around sorting. Ideally you would want to avoid situations where you are querying many records with many dependencies. It is generally fine, and useful when loading singular entities with relatives like what you are doing. Where you'd want to avoid using it, and avoid eager loading entirely would be things like search results, queries that return many top-level entities and may involve things like sorting and pagination. In these cases it is far better to use projection /w `Select` rather than returning Entities.

Comment: As for Event vs. Job, they share similar columns, but are different. I tend to look towards composition for data and object relationships before inherentence. An Event would be a specific row that references a job where the job describes what they do, and an event is a particular timed window where someone is doing it. If a job has a name and an event has a name, this isn't a case where an event "is a" job, as a job might be "dental assistant" where the event a dental assistant does is "Training".  So events have a "has a" relationship with jobs.

Comment: Thank you. I'm strongly leaning toward having just Job and the Job will have nullable properties Where and When. And I'll probably do `builder.OwnsOne(org => org.Where/When()` because 90% of the items are events (have a Where & When). That will be clean even if the When has a 1:many relationship - correct? TIA